# Cannot find symbol class newLatLng

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am following a tutorial on writing apps with Google Maps Android API v2. I encountered a problem when I tried to do the following:
`CameraUpdate update = new CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(LOCATION_HOME);`
It produces an error: cannot find symbol class newLatLng. When I type in `CameraUpdateFactory.` IDE suggests "newLatLng" but then it cannot resolve it. I added  `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'` to my gradle. No rebuilding, cleaning, invalidating caches work.
Any ideas on how to make this work? Thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually is `CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(LOCATION_HOME);`

No need to use `new` operator since your are using the factory.

Comment: Such a silly mistake, can't believe I didn't notice it. Thank you.